# Yii2 CRUD issue

Tags: php, yii2

My Yii2 app is based on advanced template. I created CRUD for a model named `Navigation` in backend side.

Now when I try to open `domain.com/navigation/index` getting `Unable to resolve the request navigation/index`.
 [image]

For information I placed this snippet in `common/config/main.php`

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a .htaccess file with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php  

</IfModule>

<IfModule php5_module>
  php_value session.cookie_httponly true
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx, but here you can find the config at Recommended Nginx Configuration: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems possible. Maybe your VM doesn't allow pretty URL than you could test your crud at least.

Just adjust the script Url for your needs as well as the other options

```
  'urlManagerBackend'=>[
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'scriptUrl' => '/admin',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/admin',
    ],
```

For any trouble here is the forum post: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60118-creating-links-from-backend-to-frontend-and-frontend-to-backend/page__fromsearch__1

Another problem could be that you are using auth rules or that your controller is in the wrong folder. Or the view file not in the folder navigation.

But first try disabling pretty URL to point out if it is server side problem or with the scripts